# Who created Hefty Smurf's tattoo?

Tags: smurfs

In the Smurfs universe Hefty originally did not have a tattoo but later on he had one.

Whether we are going from the start on not I am trying to understand who gave him his tattoo? Do we have a Tattooer smurf?

Comment: Are you ignoring the possibility that he just did it himself? http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Tattoos-Stick-n-Poke/

Comment: It's impolite to ask a Smurf how he smurfed his smurf.

Comment: I doubt there is an in-universe answer to this question. I don't recall any episode which addresses this (although it has been a long time since I watched the show). That doesn't seem like a topic that a children's TV show would get into, at least not back then.

Comment: Do Smurfs questions really belong on this part of the site?

Comment: @Richard I am not ignoring it. It is around in the scope of who did it

Comment: I have no source, but it'd be reasonable to assume he was born with it, or rather created, since all 105 Smurfs were created with magic.

Comment: @T-1000 - I'd say The Smurfs universe as a whole falls pretty squarely in the realm of sci-fi/fantasy. Arguments could be made regarding specific media, but it's definitely fantasy overall.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### There was no in-universe origin or Smurf who put the tattoo on Hefty Smurf. The tattoo was a concession made by the originator of the Smurfs Pierre Culliford when they were made into an animation series. It was part of the individualization process to give each Smurf a separate identity.

#### History of the Smurfs

In 1947, Belgian cartoonist Pierre Culliford, better known as Peyo, created a comic called Johan et Pirlouit about a young boy and his faithful (if boastful and cheating) dwarf sidekick. In 1958, in the ninth issue of the comic, the duo met tiny, blue-skinned creatures called "Les Schtroumpfs." These creatures, which later became the Smurfs, were such a hit that they got their own comic series.

[image]

> - Pierre Culliford (June 25, 1928 – December 24, 1992), known as Peyo, was a Belgian comics artist, perhaps best known for the creation of The Smurfs comic strip from which the cartoon show is based. His work is being carried on by his son Thierry Culliford, who has currently adopted the pen name Peyo for all future works through Studio Peyo.

**When Hanna-Barbara created the cartoon in the eighties, they wanted to recreate the little blue Smurfs as the stars of the show.**

- There were over [105 unique Smurfs](http://bluebuddies.com/help/smurf_names_and_list_of_the_smurfs.htm) but very little to distinguish them onscreen. Hence, their clothing, habits or attributes had to be established to make them able to be identified.
- Hefty (also known as Strongman Smurf) being the strongest couldn't be seen walking around town carrying stuff all the time, so the signature strong-man tattoo became his trademark symbol.

Comment: Besides, back then nothing said "Tough guy" like a tattoo. Unlike today.

Comment: @Omegacron How true !!!!